# Write on 3 lines in ciruitikz diagram

Tags: circuitikz

On a `circuitikz` diagram, I would like to be able to write an annotation on 3 lines: I arrive of course on 2 lines using the command

```
\draw (0,0) to[rmeter, t=GBF, l2=\SI{1}{\kHz} and \SI{0.05}{\V}]
```

but I cannot add on a 3rd line `resistance $r$` to the rmeter.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[rmeter, t=GBF, l2=\SI{1}{\kHz} and \SI{0.05}{\V}] ++(0,3)  --++(1.5,0) coordinate(charge) to[vR, mirror, invert] ++(0,-3) --++(-1.5,0);
\draw (charge) --++(1.5,0) to[rmeter, t=V] ++(0,-3) --++(-1.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a bit of a hack, and I can't check now, but you can try `and {\SI{0.05}{\V} \\  resistance $r$}`. The correct way is to use a normal label with a stack like the ones you can get from package `stackengine`. Tomorrow I'll answer if nobody chimes in.

Comment: @Rmano it works anyway

Comment: No, it doesn't work, there is an error... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`l2` labels are put in a `tabular` environment, so you can try and cheat a bit by adding a two-line second argument. But it is dangerous; braces are stripped and re-positioned during key processing, so it's easy to have an error. In this case,

```
   ... and {\SI{0.05}{\V} \\  resistance $r$}
```

gives an error in recent `circuitikz` and

```
   ... and \SI{0.05}{\V} \\  resistance $r$
```

will work, but that's not guaranteed at all. (The bracing of key-values changed between 1.2.2 and recent releases; that should be transparent to the user *unless* doing undocumented things like that (Yes I know I was the first in suggesting it `;-)`)).

The correct way of going multiline is to [use the `stackengine` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/stackengine), and doing something similar to what I did for the voltmeter here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages, straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to[rmeter, t=GBF, 
    % this is more or less an hack
    l2=\SI{1}{\kHz} and \SI{0.05}{\V} \\ resistance $r$] ++(0,3)
    --++(1.5,0) coordinate(charge) to[vR, mirror, invert]
    ++(0,-3) --++(-1.5,0);
    \draw (charge) --++(1.5,0) to[rmeter, t=V,
    % better like this
    l = {\Centerstack[l]{{first line} {second line} {third line}}}] ++(0,-3) --++(-1.5,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]